# Network adapters cannot start (Code 10)

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, drivers

### **Symptoms**

- After restarting computer both wireless and Ethernet adapter will not start
- Going to device manager (devmgmt.msc) and disabling/re-enabling wireless driver allows wireless driver to work
- Doing the same for Ethernet causes causes mmc.exe to hang and eventually fails to start driver.

---

### **Attempted fixes**

In an effort to reduce generic boiler-plate answers, these are the steps I have taken to try and rule out what is causing the issue.

- **Reinstall drivers** -> **Failure**. This yields the same result for wireless adapter as disable/re-enabling it (success). Reinstalling Ethernet adapter hangs mmc.exe, then fails with same error code (code 10).
- **Reinstall drivers using files provided by manufacturer's website (ensure using latest driver)** -> **Failure.** Same result as reinstalling drivers from device manager.
- **Disable antivirus/Disable firewall** -> **Failure.** Tried two different antiviruses (antiviruses integrate into firewall) Eset NOD32 and Bitdefender (Bitdefender cannot be completely "disabled").
- **Go back previous build** -> **Failure.** No change in symptoms.
- **Reset computer (but keep personal files)** -> **Temporary success**, restarting enough times causes symptoms to come back.
- **Clean Install** -> **Temporary success**, restarting enough times causes symptoms to come back.

---

### **Hypothesis**

I have a strong suspicion that Windows Update may be corrupting my drivers, although at this point I would not completely rule out the possibility that an application I have installed keeps on corrupting the driver. [Here is a link which encloses my installed programs.](http://pastebin.com/KfJvprE4)

---

### **Additional information**

**Events**: [Click here to download relevant Events (.evtx)](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AoF09IH6hB0GgtxGY5acKTxfG9MNDQ)

**Ethernet Adapter Event:** `Device PCI\VEN_1969&DEV_E0A1&SUBSYS_11581462&REV_10\4&f8d6983&0&00E3 requires further installation.`

**Detailed Device Status:**

```
This device cannot start. (Code 10)

 {Operation Failed}
 The requested operation was unsuccessful.
```

**Troubleshooter:**

Troubleshooter simply says hardware or software problem. Basically the network troubleshooter says a lot about nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure out the issue by using [restore points](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17127/windows-back-up-restore) and narrowing down when the computer would exhibit symptoms.

It turns out the issue was caused by **Primo Ramdisk**. For some reason the software seems to cause my network adapters to not be able to start when I have a RAM disk that boots an image file on startup.

I appears this is a freak issue that is specific to the software and/or hardware because no one else has reported this issue, and I never had this issue on an older device with which I ran the software on.

Edit: (2017) Primo Ramdisk no longer causes network adapter failures.

Answer (score 0):

So, resetting Windows brings "temporary success". It looks like a problem with 3rd party software (including your antivirus that cannot be disabled). Malware infection or hardware problem cannot be excluded as well.